# Reusing Spark SQL code in an on demand web service

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a process written in pyspark that runs some complex logic on large batches of data and is run periodically. There is also high demand to enable users to run the logic on demand on small subsets of data according to a query and get results fast. It would be really expensive and hard to maintain another copy of the logic in another framework like pandas, so I am trying to instead run the logical parts of the process in local mode (`master=local[n]`) packaged in a flask service that the users can then send requests to. The service queries a database with the input data according to the user's request, runs the logical parts of the process and then returns the result to the user.

It works, the problem is it is too slow. I have managed to narrow down the bad performance to two main bottlenecks:

The first one is two python udfs that take a long time to run.

The other one is that it takes about 10 seconds to run all of the spark sql code excluding the action for each request, and 10 more seconds from running the action to the job actually starting to run and appearing in the spark ui. From observing the logs I suspect it's the code generation but I am unsure.

My questions are:

1. Is there any way to reduce the amount of time it takes to run the spark sql code of the job up to the action? I have tried avoiding to recompute the dataframe by for example writing the raw data to a csv as an input, running the action, and then for the next request overwritng the csv and running the action again on the same dataframe, hoping to get results for the new data, but it didn't seem to work.
2. Is there any way to reduce the delay from running the action to the job starting?
3. Are there any better alternatives to repurpose the spark code other than what I am doing right now?
4. What general optimizations can I do to make the jobs run faster in local mode?

I know there are solutions like apache Livy and spark connect that allow you to send requests to a remote spark cluster thus saving the hassle of your app being the driver. This may help for handling requests from many users, however it doesn't seem logical to me that these products would solve the 20 seconds of overhead launching each job

thanks

Comment: could you mention the spark version you are running and the type of transformations in UDFs? In most cases, you can divide the UDF operations into smaller operations with spark APIs.